# Values are not being passed under RequestScope

Tags: jsf-2

I've below set of pages & respective MPB's and I've organised them as below.
1)

```
class ManagedBeanBase {
  protected String mode;
}
```

2) page1.xhtml

```
   <ui:composition>
    <ui:define name="contentArea">
        <f:metadata>
     <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{page1MPB.preProcess}" />
    </f:metadata>
               ...
               ...
    <h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGroup>
            <h:commandButton value="continue" id="button_continue"
                actionListener="#{page1MPB.postProcess}" />
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGrid>
    </ui:define>
  </ui:composition>
```

3)

```
@RequestScoped
@ManagedBean(name="page1MPB")
Page1MPB extends ManagedBeanBase
{
  public void preProcess() {setMode("1");}
  public void postProcess(ActionEvent event) {
     System.out.println("MODE during submit ["+getMode()+"]);
  }

}
```

Now the issue is, it is displaying 'null' value during submit.

Can any one suggest please? Let me know alternative solution if it is not possible to get mode value during submit. Please note that mode value is getting displayed under session scope.

Comment: Did you forget the `@ManagedBean` annotation or is it a typo in this post? Also make sure the annotations are importing the `javax.faces.bean.*` package

Comment: @ManagedBean annotation was present in my actual code and there was no issue with import statements.

Comment: I posted an answer. Note I tested your code and had to change a few things to make it work (i.e. make the Page1MPB a `public class`, and other small things but maybe you only posted a partial code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `preRenderView` is used before rendering the view to run some custom code before displaying the rest of the view (with possibly displaying the value computed in the preRenderView). The rest follows standard scope fundamentals.
Your managed bean is `RequestScope`, so the preProcess sets the `mode` to 1 and then that's it.
When you click submit, it becomes a new request so the `mode` is null. Change to `ViewScoped` (or higher scope) to keep the value of the `preRenderView`.

Here is the output (I added Lifecycle phases output):

`RequestScoped:`
INFO: Before Phase RESTORE_VIEW 1
INFO: After Phase RESTORE_VIEW 1
INFO: Before Phase RENDER_RESPONSE 6
**INFO: MODE during preProcess [1]**
**INFO: MODE during preProcess [1]**
INFO: After Phase RENDER_RESPONSE 6
 INFO: After Phase RENDER_RESPONSE 6
 // Press "Continue"
INFO: Before Phase RESTORE_VIEW 1
INFO: After Phase RESTORE_VIEW 1
INFO: Before Phase APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
INFO: After Phase APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
INFO: Before Phase PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
INFO: After Phase PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
INFO: Before Phase UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
INFO: After Phase UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
INFO: Before Phase INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
**INFO: MODE during submit [null]**
INFO: After Phase INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
INFO: Before Phase RENDER_RESPONSE 6
**INFO: MODE during preProcess [1]**
**INFO: MODE during preProcess [1]**
**INFO: MODE during preProcess [1]**
INFO: After Phase RENDER_RESPONSE 6

`ViewScoped:`

INFO: Before Phase RESTORE_VIEW 1
 INFO: After Phase RESTORE_VIEW 1
 INFO: Before Phase RENDER_RESPONSE 6
 **INFO: MODE during preProcess [1]**
 **INFO: MODE during preProcess [1]**
 INFO: After Phase RENDER_RESPONSE 6
 // Press "Continue"
 INFO: Before Phase RESTORE_VIEW 1
 INFO: After Phase RESTORE_VIEW 1
 INFO: Before Phase APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
 INFO: After Phase APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES 2
 INFO: Before Phase PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
 INFO: After Phase PROCESS_VALIDATIONS 3
 INFO: Before Phase UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
 INFO: After Phase UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES 4
 INFO: Before Phase INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
**INFO: MODE during submit [1]**
 INFO: After Phase INVOKE_APPLICATION 5
 INFO: Before Phase RENDER_RESPONSE 6
 **INFO: MODE during preProcess [1]**
 **INFO: MODE during preProcess [1]**
 **INFO: MODE during preProcess [1]**
 INFO: After Phase RENDER_RESPONSE 6

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and answer. It is working under ViewScope.